# uXlib.h Which package have this lib file?

Tags: ubuntu, c++

I am getting an error uXlib.h not found while compiling a program, written in c++

I think the lib file is related UIM/X from the following link

[motif.ics.com/sites/default/files/ReferenceManual.pdf‎](http://motif.ics.com/sites/default/files/ReferenceManual.pdf%E2%80%8E)

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: @Bob, ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 2):

In Debian-based distributions (including Ubuntu), use `dpkg -S uXlib.h` to find out, from which package a file named uXlib.h comes from (if that package is installed, it will find it).

If that package is not installed, you might want to install `apt-file` as described here: http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/findfile.htm.

I believe that your file should be in some `dev` package as headers go there, may be something like `libmotif-dev`. UPDATE: no, didn't find it in [libmotif-dev](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/i386/libmotif-dev/filelist).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sovle this issue by copying all the header files from

[ftp://ftp.hq.eso.org/pub/linux/scisoft4/midas/02FEB/gui/GraphLib/libsrc/uimxR5/include](http://ftp.hq.eso.org/pub/linux/scisoft4/midas/02FEB/gui/GraphLib/libsrc/uimxR5/include)

to /usr/include.

I don't know if its the right way.

Comment: Usually, when you manually install a program (not from a package via dpkg, apt, aptitude or synaptic, but manually by downloading a file) it goes to `/usr/local` filesystem, reserved for local systems administrator manually installed program. So typically, you would put your header file to `/usr/local/include` as in http://wiki.debian.org/FMOD#Headers, also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/17545/where-does-ubuntu-store-its-library-files. Though, it varies from distro to distro, some distros put even locally installed headers to /usr/include.